# What if a trigger fails?

Tags: mysql, triggers

If I run an insert query, but I have a trigger on a table to increment another value based upon the trigger, but there's something wrong with the trigger, will it still execute my query?

Comment: @cdhowie, I think he was asking which database engine.  MySQL supports many.

Comment: is it a Before Insert or After Insert trigger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following reference [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) should help. Basically, an error during either a BEFORE or AFTER trigger results in failure of the entire statement that caused trigger invocation.

You shouldn't need to test this out, but if you wanted to quickly test this out, simple create a dummy table with a failed insert trigger. The results would be very clear from there.

Hope I helped

Comment: This is a little misleading - the statement fails, but it's only rolled back if you're using a transactional table type (eg, innodb). For myisam, it may leave intermediate changes permanently committed.